# using array for URLSearchParams in vue3

Tags: arrays, loops, append, vuejs3

i want to append key and value of array , using for axos request
here is the array
const

```
schedule = ref({
  "userId" : 13,
  "sunday" : ["mornig","afternoon","nigh"],
  "monday" : ["afternoon","nigh"],
  "wednesday" : ["mornig","afternoon"]
})
```

to append manuallya i can do like this

```
params.append("userId",data.value.userId)
params.append("sunday[0]",data.value.sunday[0])
params.append("sunday[1]",data.value.sunday[1])
params.append("sunday[2]",data.value.sunday[2])
params.append("monday[0]",data.value.monday[0])
params.append("monday[1]",data.value.monday[1])
params.append("wednesday[0]",data.value.wednesday[0])
params.append("wednesday[1]",data.value.wednesday[1])
```

but this will be problim if length of the schedule time l (morning,night ...) unknown
i do like this

```
 let i = 0
    for(let j in data.value){
      console.log(j+$[i++])
    }
```

and also loop using for in and for of , but none of them are success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "just" need to do a nested iteration. Loop through object, and if any value is an array, loop through the array. Here's an example code to flatten the dataset. Just note that instead of `flattenData(schedule)` you'd need to pass the ref's value with `flattenData(schedule.value)`.

```js
const schedule = {
  userId: 13,
  sunday: ["mornig", "afternoon", "nigh"],
  monday: ["afternoon", "nigh"],
  wednesday: ["morning", "afternoon"],
};

function flattenData(data) {
  const o = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((dataKey) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data[dataKey])) {
      data[dataKey].forEach(
        (_, nestedArrayIndex) =>
          (o[`${dataKey}[${nestedArrayIndex}]`] =
            data[dataKey][nestedArrayIndex])
      );
    } else {
      o[dataKey] = data[dataKey];
    }
  });
  return o;
}

// show flattened data
console.log(flattenData(schedule));

// prepare params
const params = new URLSearchParams("");

// populate
Object.entries(flattenData(schedule)).forEach(([k,v]) => params.append(k, v))

// result:
console.log(params.toString())
```